# Союз "а" в предложениях

Tags: союзы

Может ли союз "а" в предложении "Ты глупая, а он смешной" иметь соединительное значение?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

В общем случае союз всегда используется для связи (**соединения**) или однородных членов предложения, или частей сложного предложения.

Простые предложения в составе ССП связаны сочинительными союзами, которые делятся  НА СЛЕДУЮЩИЕ  ГРУППЫ: соединительные, разделительные, противительные, пояснительные, присоединительные.

**Союз А** относится к группе противительных сочинительных союзов (А, НО, ДА=НО, ЗАТО, ОДНАКО, ЖЕ),  но при этом его основным значением   является **сопоставление**.   При помощи союза А сопоставляются или противопоставляются факты, которые различаются  по какому-либо признаку, **но не являются взаимоисключающими, а сосуществуют.**

Этим союз А **отличается от противительного союза НО**, когда обозначаются события, которые **исключают, ограничивают или  противоречат** друг другу.

Поэтому можно сказать, что в заданном предложении союз А обозначает не соединение, а сопоставление.

У союза А бывают **дополнительные значения**: выделение, присоединение/распространение,  иногда несоответствие. Тогда попробуем сравнить два предложения:

Ты глупая, а он смешной (сопоставление и присоединение/распространение).

Ты глупая, а он умный (сопоставление и противопоставление).

Answer (score 0):

Значение - да, хотя и очень слабое. Но по сути это союз противительный, никуда не деться.

Подробности - у Sibylla