# Корректно ли составлено предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы

Верно ли построено предложение?
*Не как захватчики, **но** как освободители.*
Союз "но" корректно употреблять в данном случае?

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Это не ошибка, но такой выбор союза придаёт предложению необычный, торжественно-архаичный стиль, уместность которого зависит от контекста. Пример из Евангелия от Матфея:

> **Не** мир пришел я принести, **но** меч.

Answer (score 0):

Не ошибка. Но это не стандартно.

Разница с союзом "а":
*Не как захватчики, а как освободители.* || Части связаны между собой противопоставлением.
*Не как захватчики. Но как освободители.* || Части уже не так связаны. Можно оформить отдельными предложениями. "Но" создаёт оттенок добавочной информации. На первой части делается больший смысловой акцент, нежели в первом варианте.

Answer (score 0):

**Чтобы рассуждать о союзах, надо с ними познакомиться**, можно по этой ссылке: [Союз "а" в предложениях](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423679/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7-%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)

Мы привыкли считать конструкцию **НЕ...А противопоставлением,** но основное значение у союза А — это **сопоставление**, например у Цветаевой: "Я глупая, а ты умён, Живой, а я остолбенелая".

Настоящим же **противительным союзом является  союз НО**, он обозначаются события, которые исключают, ограничивают или противоречат друг другу.

Поэтому конструкция **НЕ...НО имеет усилительное значение**, и это связано с контекстом.

***Не как захватчики, но как освободители.***

Вариант 1 (стандартный): **НЕ...А**

Это другие — захватчики. А они не захватчики, а освободители.  Обозначено деление на захватчиков и освободителей и сделан выбор.

Вариант 2. **НЕ...НО**

Они не захватчики, но освободители. При инверсии: Но они освободители, не захватчики. Здесь сопоставления и выбора нет, но есть **взаимоисключение**. Это более сильная позиция.

Другой пример: *Солнце, не огнистое, не раскалённое, как во время знойной засухи, не тускло-багровое, как перед бурей, **но светлое и приветливо лучезарное**, мирно всплывает из-под узкой и длинной*.

Здесь сопоставительный союз А вообще не подходит, а союз НО смотрится вполне на месте.